# How to check if jQuery load() is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

Does anyone knows how to check if this jQuery `load()` function is empty:

```
    jQuery(this).children('.content-from-far-away').load(URLvar +' .content-item:first-child');
```

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by empty?

Comment: I mean if there were no .content-item:first-child at all (if the page had no .content-item elements)

Comment: If a `jQuery(selector)` call finds nothing, it's `length` property will be `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope useful for you.

```
var element = jQuery(this)
             
if (element)
{
  //you can use the load function here without undefined or something like that
   element = elment.children('.content-from-far-away')
                   .load(URLvar +' .content-item:first-child'); 


}
```

Comment: I finally used this:      jQuery(this).children('.content-tagged').load(href +' .content-item:first-child',function(data){
     if (jQuery(this).is(":empty")){ jQuery(this).html("There are no posts with the requested tag."); }
    });